# Function that adds a property to an object

Tags: javascript, flowtype

What would be the correct/preferred way of adding Flow annotations to a function like this?

```
function addBar(foo) {
  foo.bar = 10
  return foo
}
```

Let's say I have the following types:

```
type Foo = { foo: string }
type FooBar = { foo: string, bar: number }
```

and I would like the function to take in a `Foo` and return a `FooBar`.

So far, the best solutions I've come up with are this:

```
function addBar(foo: Foo): FooBar {
  const fooBar: FooBar = { ...foo, bar: 10 }
  return fooBar
}
```

which creates a copy of the object and relies on rest properties. Or this:

```
function addBar(foo: Foo): FooBar {
  const fooBar: FooBar = (foo: any)
  fooBar.bar = 10
  return fooBar
}
```

which requires some hacky casting.

In theory, this should be achievable without any casting or copying. But can Flow's dynamic analysis detect this? And are there other approaches better suited for this use case?

Comment: Well, changing the type of an existing object by adding a property *is* hacky casting.

Comment: In general Flow doesn't model the side effects of function calls. So, there is no way for it to understand that calling a function mutates the object you have. You've correctly identified that making a copy allows Flow to understand what's going on, and that doing exactly what you want requires you to circumvent the type system (which in some cases is okay -- it's really up to you).

Comment: Hmm, good points... it didn't seem hacky to me at first because I was probably thinking of it as a conversion. But now that I think of it, creating a copy of the object makes perfect sense if it's a conversion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the `foo` object literal, which will will not support additional mutations unless specifically annotated.

To simplify your example even further, the following would throw a flow error:

```
const hello = { hello: 'hello' };
hello.world = 'world';

18: hello.world = 'world';
          ^ property `world`. Property not found in
18: hello.world = 'world';
    ^ object literal
```

However the following would not:

```
const hello: { hello: 'hello', [someOtherKey: string]: mixed };
hello.world = 'world';

// no errors!
```

However, allowing ["property variance"](https://flowtype.org/docs/objects.html#objects-as-maps) effectively unseals `hello` and turns it into a map, opening it to silent type errors if you did not want a property to be added.

Another simple way to annotate your method would be to do the following:

```
type FooBarType = {
  foo: mixed,
  bar?: number
}

function addBar(foo: FooBarType): FooBarType {
  foo.bar = 10;
  return foo;
}

addBar({ foo: 'hello' }); // no errors!
```

This ensures that the type of foo can support having bar added to it. This isn't the same as actually having the property. You generally don't want your methods circumventing object types to mutate their properties. Rather, define the object in such a way that it can support the mutations. Otherwise use a functional approach, and return a new object. The following would allow you to keep foo sealed:

```
function functionalAddBar(foo: Foo): FooBar {
  return Object.assign({}, foo, { bar: 10 });
}
```

Comment: Good points and the functional approach would probably fit my use case best. The example with FooBarType does not seem to be error-free, though: https://flowtype.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAQgQwE4BVzQLxQN4BQUUAZggFxQC2AlgB4QAmANEVAEZqUB2ArlewioCAXwIESvbgGNgNONyjJGjFKgAUZOJXhI0mSAEodCNQeiFiWgHSdUUXAEYADAG42qCMF6pFW92IEyqpo6nikFFAA5AAWEAA28XBRUCKGQA

Comment: sorry, I forgot that bar needed to be optional. https://flowtype.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAQgQwE4BVzQLxQN4BQUUAZggFxQC2AlgB4QAmANEVAEZoD8lAdgK5V2EVAQC+BAiX68AxsBpxeUZI0YpUACjJxK8JGkyQAlHoQaj0QsR0A6Tqii4AjAAYA3G1QRg-VMp1PCQJVdTRNPFIKKAByAAsIABtEuBioMWMgA